# Why are Stack Exchange sites not hosted on a cloud?

Tags: discussion, support, hosting

Could anyone please explain the key reasons why Stack Exchange is not hosted on a cloud service?

I fully understand that choosing between hosting on a cloud versus hosting on own servers requires thorough analysis, and I don't mean to doubt the choice made by the Stack Exchange team. But I am curious about how or why this decision was made.

Comment: Because it would constantly be down, like reddit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are the main reasons in my opinion:

1. To have full/fine grained control on their hardware/software
2. To enjoy in details every aspect of their system learning and tweaking something new everyday
3. To avoid lock/in to some platform
4. To have the pleasure to spend money in super beefy and powerful servers

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [**this blog post**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/re-launching-stack-exchange-data-explorer/). They're explaining why they moved the [**Stack Exchange Data Explorer**](https://data.stackexchange.com/) from Azure to their servers.

The same reasoning can be applied to the SE network.

Comment: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56719/is-odata-stackexchange-com-down-for-everyone-or-just-me and related questions